# convert html text to normal text

Tags: php, html

I want to display HTML code to normal text.using rich text box I had inserted the values as HTML in db.I need to display as normal text after fetched.
  fetched value was displayed as `<p>dsadad sadsdfsd</p>`
   desire output `dsadad sadsdfsd`

```
<textarea class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="description">
    <?= html_entity_decode(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$fet['description'])); ?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: [strip_tags()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: So you want to get raw text from HTML?

Comment: try htmlentities : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: ya need to get raw text

Answer (score 2):

You can use strip tags for this purpose:

```
echo strip_tags("<p>dsadad sadsdfsd</p>");
```

Desired output will be:

```
dsadad sadsdfsd
```

This function strips a string from HTML, XML, and PHP tags. In this example, the `<p>` tag gets stripped. You can also allow tags to be used but tags are striped

```
echo strip_tags("<b>dsadad sadsdfsd</b>","<b>"); // Allow <b> tag here
```

Here you allow the effect of `<b>` tag. But tag will be striped. The desired output will be:

**dsadad sadsdfsd**

For deep information you can see [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Use strip_tags($data) function, hope this help you

```
<textarea><?php echo strip_tags($your_data); ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

`strip_tag` is your friend here. it will take out `html` tags out and return whatever is left in the string

```
<textarea class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="description"><?php strip_tags($fet['description']); ?></textarea>
```

More details on `strip_tags` [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)